# Use Blaze UI Component sAlert in Meteor 1.2.1 with Angular

Tags: angularjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I had a working Meteor App with Angular and Blaze before the 1.2.1 Update came out, but now it´s not possible anymore to use for example

```
{{>sAlert}}
```

in my Application.

There is a helper package called "angular-with-blaze", where you have the possibility to include Blaze templates, and I thought I´d wrap the {{>sAlert}} into a custom template, and load it with

```
<template name="custom">
    {{>sAlert}}
</template>
<blaze-template name="custom"></blaze-template>
```

But it tells me, that the template wasn´t found.

So what is now the way to go for including such components in my meteor based angular app?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the problem? What is 'not possible'? Do you see errors messages? What are those? And isn't there a mistake in you template? Looks like invalid markup, starttag=template, endtag=custom-template.

Comment: @JosHarink to sum it up, I´m using Meteor with Angular. According to their blog entry I have removed the blaze stuff, but I want to use some packages with UI components (e.g. {{>sAlert}} ) listed on atmosphere which are actually using blaze. Indeed there was a typing mistake. I´ve corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. Put the sAlert template helper in a blaze template and render that template with blaze-template. But you need to put the blaze-template line in your angular html file and the actual Blaze template in another html file where you only put your Blaze templates.

example-list.ng.html:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <h1>Sample</h1>
    </header>

    <blaze-template name="test1"></blaze-template>
    <blaze-template name="test2"></blaze-template>
</div>
```

And another file for your Blaze templates:
blaze-templates.html:

```
<template name="test1">
    {{> sAlert}}
    Hello {{visitor}}
</template>

<template name="test2">
    Hello {{customer}}
</template>
```

* because I render both test1 and test2 to the same page, only test1 can have the sAlert template helper. If on different pages, repeat the template helper. But that is not part of your question, it is how sAlert works.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried it yet but I will let you know if it works for me