# Using Blaze Template in Angular Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use [`useraccounts:bootstrap`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/bootstrap/) in an Angular Meteor app by using [`urigo:angular-blaze-template`](https://github.com/urigo/angular-blaze-template/) package to use the blaze template `{{> atForm}}` provided by `useraccounts:bootstrap`.

**Problem:** I'm getting an error on the webpage: `meteorTemplate: There is no template with the name 'todoList'`. Any ideas?

**useraccounts.html**

```
<template name="todoList">
    {{> atForm}}
</template>

<blaze-template name="todoList"></blaze-template>
```

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

    $stateProvider
        .state('useraccounts', {
            url: '/useraccounts',
            templateUrl: 'client/useraccounts/views/useraccounts.html',
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/foo')
})
```

---

Followed the suggestions of Jos Jarink, the missing template error is gone! But `{{> atForm }}` does not contain any content, only the following code that is nested inside the `uiView` `div`.

`blaze-html-templates` package has been removed, adding this back does not seem to make any difference.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- uiView:  -->
    <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
        <blaze-template name="atForm" class="ng-scope">
            <div class="at-form ng-scope">
            </div>
        </blaze-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## Update

**Github Repo:** https://github.com/nyxynyx/useraccounts-angular

Uncommenting `blaze-html-templates` in `.meteor/packages` gives the error

```
Errors prevented startup: While determining active plugins: 
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates and templating) are both trying to handle *.html
```

Comment: I've answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34375238/1426570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Blaze template in another file as where you put your Angular html. That is, put the `<template>` in another file, the `<blaze-template>` stays in your Angular html file.

**useraccounts.html**

```
<blaze-template name="todoList"></blaze-template>
```

**useraccounts_blaze.html**

```
<template name="todoList">
    {{> atForm}}
</template>
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073593/5543045

**Update and check for atForm presence:**

If you want to check whether atForm or any other template was found by blaze-template, you can add a simple template helper that tries to find the template name.
Something like:

```
Template.todoList.helpers({
    isThatTemplateHere: function (name) {
        var tmpl = Template[name];
        if (tmpl)
            return name + ' was found';
        else
            return name + ' was not found';
    }
});
```

And in your template:

```
<template name="todoList">
    {{isThatTemplateHere "atForm"}}
    {{> atForm}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, the missing template error is now gone, but nothing from `atForm` template is being rendered on the page. Any ideas? Updated question with more details.

Comment: I added the `useraccounts:bootstrap` package and copy/pasted your html with atForm and it renders as expected. It shows a sign-in box. It looks like  the atForm template is not found by blaze-template in your case. If a template is not found, blaze-template will not notify us with some warning or error, it just doesn't render anything and that is what you are experiencing.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code to check whether atForm can be found. That might help investigating the problem of atForm not rendered. Change your line `<blaze-template name="atForm" class="ng-scope">` to `<blaze-template name="todoList" class="ng-scope">`.

Comment: I tried using `atForm` using a clean meteor project and ended up with the same problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, let me create a github repo to recreate the problem

Comment: Updated questoin with github repo. Hope we can solve it!

Comment: You commented out blaze-html-templates in your packages, probably after you ran into this problem and trying to fix it. Include it again and it should work.

Comment: I uncommeted `blaze-html-templates` but got the error `Errors prevented startup:

While determining active plugins:
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates and templating) are both trying to handle *.html`

Comment: I am confused now :) I suggested to have a todoList template. That does not work but with atForm it works ! Another confusing thing is that I have a project that has the `blaze-html-templates` package together with angular. And when mixing Blaze and Agular and having Blaze templates I think you need `blaze-html-templates`. When I leave it out and debug the global `Template` it contains atForm but not todoList. I read something about clearing the cache and naming convention name.ng.html. Did both but no result.

Comment: Can you push your working meteor project to Github so I can take a look?

Comment: Just added a repo I used to answer a similar question about mixing Angular and Blaze (issue was with package juliancwirko:s-alert which has also a template in the package calles sAlert). https://github.com/MGA1600/angular-blaze.git

Comment: I've just released the new angular-with-blaze 1.3.1 which I think has a fix for some of what you are experiencing - https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/releases